# Ejabberd Victim of Systemd Security Enhancements?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, container, proxmox, ejabberd

I can't get ejabberd to start on a Ubuntu 18.04 Server that's installed inside a Proxmox linux container.

During install I get this error:

```
Setting up ejabberd (18.01-2) ...
Job for ejabberd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ejabberd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ejabberd, action "start" failed.
* ejabberd.service - A distributed, fault-tolerant Jabber/XMPP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ejabberd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-04-22 18:41:58 UTC; 8ms ago
     Docs: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/docs/
   Process: 1442 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl start && /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl started (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 190 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package ejabberd (--configure):
 installed ejabberd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.20) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ejabberd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I read a bug report that suggests that the problem has to do with the way Ejabberd is configured with systemd:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ejabberd/+bug/1815699

That person said that the issue had to do with these 3 settings:

1. PrivateTmp=true
2. ProtectHome=true
3. ProtectSystem=full

But he didn't say where to find them or how to change them.

I found them here:
nano /lib/systemd/system/ejabberd.service

I've tried setting them to false, commenting them out, etc. After each change I tried, I'd reboot the container and try test to see if chat was working. It wasn't.

I don't know much about systemd or ejabberd. I've installed ejabberd successfully a few times in the past, but I don't know how to get past this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://salsa.debian.org/ejabberd-packaging-team/ejabberd/blob/master/debian/README.Debian#L161-168, or in `/usr/share/doc/ejabberd/README.Debian.gz` on your system:

> With systemd >= 218 you can simply create an override with
>   `systemctl edit ejabberd.service` and put
>
> ```
> [Service]
> PrivateDevices=
> PrivateDevices=false
> NoNewPrivileges=
> NoNewPrivileges=false
> ```
>
> in there.